# Not able to get data greater than Date

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I tried mulitple types of SQL queries to get the data greater than a date

```
Select * from Table1
where Date > 2021-07-01
--or where Billing_Date > '2021-07-01'
```

Billing_Date **data type is Date**

Both variations not working, getting error:

> Syntax Error '>' cannot be applied to date, integer

*Using *Dbeaver*, database- Amazon Athena*

Comment: Try `Date > '2021-07-01'`, or  `Date > date'2021-07-01'`

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Select * from Table1
where Date > DATE('2021-07-01')
--or where Billing_Date > DATE('2021-07-01')
```

Comment: @EthanSmih Accept the answer if it works for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers